# Get Post_Parent to use slug in Get_Posts args

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I have some args that are checking the `post_parent` id to add the child pages to a select menu in a metabox.

But i'd rather not use the ID of the page as this might change, but the slug will always be the same.

```
        // POST
        array(
            'name'        => esc_html__( 'Select the previous page for the button link', 'uhd' ),
            'id'          => "{$prefix}prev_target",
            'type'        => 'post',
            // Post type
            'post_type'   => 'page',
            // Field type, either 'select' or 'select_advanced' (default)
            'field_type'  => 'select_advanced',
            'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Select an Item', 'uhd' ),
            // Query arguments (optional). No settings means get all published posts
            'query_args'  => array(
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => - 1,
                'post_parent'   => 18,
            ),
        ),
```

Uses the same args as https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 1):

You can get the post ID of your desired slug using [get_page_by_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/), and then pass the result into the args. Eg:

```
$parent_post = get_page_by_path( 'full/slug' );

$args = array(
    [...]
    'query_args' => array(
        'post_parent' => $parent_post->ID,
    ),
);
```

If this is a custom post type you'll need to pass that in as well:

```
$parent_post = get_page_by_path( 'full/slug', OBJECT, 'post-type' );
```

All this said, normally the slug of a post is the thing that can change, and not its ID. Maybe you have some unique usage scenario, but the slug is user editable (or plugin editable) while the post ID stays constant once the post has been created.